# SLD variable substitution GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a layer using this SLD style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
                           xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
                           xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
                           xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                           xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <sld:NamedLayer>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Title>Name</sld:Title>
            <sld:Abstract>Name style</sld:Abstract>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Rule>
                 <sld:Name>Polygon</sld:Name>
                  <sld:Title>Polygon</sld:Title>
                   <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <sld:Fill>
                    <sld:CssParameter name="fill">
                        <ogc:Function name="env">
                            <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>#00FFFF</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </sld:CssParameter>
                    <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                        <ogc:Function name="env">
                            <ogc:Literal>opacity</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>0.8</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </sld:CssParameter>
                    </sld:Fill>
                    <sld:Stroke>
                     <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#00FFFF</sld:CssParameter>
                     <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</sld:CssParameter>
                    </sld:Stroke>
                   </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>          
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The stroke is not set as a variable above, just the fill (that is the plan)

When not sending the env parameters, GeoServer returns this:
[image: valid style]

I am testing the URL here below, but it returns me an empty fill polygon when sending the customised variables

[image: empty polygon]

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspace/wms?
service=WMS&
version=1.1.0&
request=GetMap&
layers=workspace%3Alayer&
bbox=1%2C2%2C3%2C4&
styles=&
width=768&
height=397&
srs=EPSG%3A4326&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng&
env=color:#00FF00;opacity:0.3
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 2):

it worked by replacing in the url:

env=color:#00FF00;opacity:0.3

'#' by %23

env=color:%2300FF00;opacity:0.3

All the examples I found were using either '#' or without it, so this type of error got unnoticed, until I realised it